# Always Encrypted - create certificate error windows server 2012

Tags: powershell, always-encrypted

when i try to create certificate, column master key and column encryption key using the below PS script its works fine in windows 10

```
Import-Module "SqlServer"
$serverName = "XXX"
$databaseName ="XX"
$connStr = "Server = " + $serverName + "; Database = " + $databaseName + "; Integrated Security=true"
$connection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connStr
$connection.Connect()
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($connection)
$database = $server.Databases[$databaseName] 

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "Cert" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048


$cmkSettings = New-SqlCertificateStoreColumnMasterKeySettings -CertificateStoreLocation "LocalMachine" -Thumbprint $cert.Thumbprint 


$cmkName = "CMK1"
New-SqlColumnMasterKey -Name $cmkName -InputObject $database -ColumnMasterKeySettings $cmkSettings

$cekName = "CEK1"
New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey -Name $cekName -InputObject $database -ColumnMasterKey $cmkName
```

but getting error in windows server 2012. if i remove the following:

```
-Subject, -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048
```

and use `-DNSName` only then it just create column master key and throw error while create column encryption key.

someone please provide me correct syntax which works on Windows server 2012 and create certificate , column master key and column encryption key?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to **Create a self-signed certificate using PowerShell** section of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted).

To be used as Always encrypted CMKs, certificates require a specific configuration.

You should be able to create a certificate to be used as CMK using the following commands

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate is a Windows PowerShell cmdlet that creates a self-signed certificate. The below examples show how to generate a certificate that can be used as a column master key for Always Encrypted.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "AlwaysEncryptedCert" -CertStoreLocation Cert:CurrentUser\My -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 

# To create a certificate in the local machine certificate store location you need to run the cmdlet as an administrator.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "AlwaysEncryptedCert" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048
```

This should work with Server 2012, you will have to install makecert utility if it does not exist:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=Always Encrypted Certificate - exported" -pe -sr CurrentUser -r -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.11 -ss my -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" -sy 1 -len 2048 -a sha256
```

Comment: -Subject, -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 commands are not supported in Windows server 2012. its works fine in Windows10. i am looking for  Windows server 2012.